# Why python3 on command line invokes python2?

Tags: python

I am experiencing an odd python thing! I can only use python 2; all other pythons (python3.4, -3.5) are gone; They exist in usr/bin, but I can't use them. For example, usr/bin/python3.4 invokes pyhton2.7. Two days ago everything was normal; I was using python3.4 just fine. All I did in last two days was to install a flask environment and I also purged teamviewer from my ubuntu.

Comment: add output `ls -l usr/bin/python3.4` it seems symbolic links created

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question.

Comment: you may have encounter an issue with environment path

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to solve it, if you have Python 3 installed is typing python3.

Also, check this link, it probably solves your problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Comment: that didn't work; I was even calling python3.4 with full path. I reinstalled python3.4 and it works now with all previous dependencies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check links in /usr/bin

```
ls -al | grep python
```

All python interpreters must be linked with our executable files.

Call python 3 with version, for example:

```
python3.4
```

Do not change symbolik link from python to python3, this can crash system scripts.

Install and use virtualenvwrapper:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Check virtualenvwrapper location:

```
whereis virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Add into you BASH config calling virtualenvwrapper and use it for creating virtual environment with python 3:

```
mkvirtualenv myvenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4
```

Activate virtualenv and install required packages (root privilegies NOT required!):

```
workon myvenv
pip install flask
```

Call IDE from terminal with activated virtual environment for correct PATH working.

Enjoy!

Comment: So, all I did was to reinstall the python3.4; other options failed. Thanks

Comment: @dzahedia I recommend using virtualenvwrapper instead installing packages into system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.4
```

Now, everything is back to normal.